Single-source data warehouse permissions management
We (Data Platform team) are reviewing how we configure and apply permissions against our data warehouse objects, and I'm curious what tools or custom systems you might be using for this.
For context our warehouse is AWS Redshift, and tools that manage db objects include both self-hosted tools with ability to hook into the execution flow and perform arbitrary work such as dbt + dagster, as well as managed/serverless tools over which we have limited control on the execution flow and logic such as Fivetran.
Our current core issue is the variety of ways permissions can be applied (direct GRANT 1-off migrations, alter default privileges, scripts that blankly re-apply grants on a fixed schedule, tools like dbt that can be configured to apply grants immediately on table (re)creation..), which generate a lot of confusion as to where and how grants need to be applied, and how to actually apply them. The end result is a permissions model where it's really complex to understand intent, users and models that on/off fail to gain access to objects they should, misconfigured pipelines, etc.
We are looking for a more sane way to configure and apply our permissions. In my mind an ideal system in a nutshell would include:
Single source of truth for defining permissions intent over all db objects (IaaC style, terraform?)
One off:
2.a. Service does continuous reconciliation of permission intent vs current state (think k8s state reconciliation)
2.b. Permission applied/revoked on deployment (think terraform) + allow systems to read the intent (eg. sql tables) and decide how and when to re-apply permissions
With such a setup, you'd effectively be able to point end-users at a single place and system to describe permissions intent (and look it up if/when there are issues), and enforcing grants it's either something noone needs to worry about (reconcile service) or it is system owners' responsibility to integrate with the source of truth to apply permissions.
I have not come across such a tool in the wild, but we would much prefer to take on / pay for some industry standard solution than build our own.
How do you yourselves handle the messy world of SQL GRANTs management?

can you clarify how you are defining  permissions with IAM? are you assigning them to roles? why do you need to reassign on a schedule?

@Ewan this is a redshift user/group GRANT issue, not IAM. But effectively when you GRANT a permission to eg. a table to a user/group, and something re-creates that tables (eg. dbt table model), the original GRANTs are lost and have to be re-applied. Only native way around is ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES which is schema-wide only.

Do you use source co trol for your database? I think the confusion here is that it would be normal to have the table definition, including role permissions, in your source control as part of the definition of the table. So if you need to recreate it the permissions are automatically also assigned. Do you not do this kind of thing at all? or is it that you have so many permissions, maybe because you set then at a user level or something, that storing them as part of rhe table def is impractical?

on a normal db I would expect only 2 or maybe 3 roles max. i can see on a data warehouse you might have more, but not more than say 10? how many are we talking?

so just looking into this more and the state of play for source control for postgres seems awful. The advice is to literally manually write out the grants in an sql file and set it to run on every migration.

have you looked at thing like liquibase?

Liquibase looks similar to Flyway right? This is indeed something we're considering for static configuration (uswers/groups/roles, schemas) and 1-off migration management - from my understanding, systems that allow you to configure config/migrations once, and it will manage which changes have to be executed on deployment (similar to terraform dedicated to db management?).
However from my understanding they don't perform ongoing reconciliation against db state do they? Relevantly here, re-applying permissions to objects that are re-created.

"have the table definition... in your source control" - are you suggesting standard practice is to separate table definitions from data producers? eg. Liquibase defines the tables, and producers populate the tables?  This sounds quite unintuitive within the warehousing ecosystem, where tools like dbt, Fivetran, etc. all pretty much force/heavily encourage db object lifecycle control to be delegated to them to make them work. I can't immediately see a feasible way to eg. maintain table schema definitions separate from dbt sql models.
But we might be missing a trick.

One thing worth highlighting is perhaps our permissions model is too open - I've thought in the past that it would be ideal if we could manage permissions purely at the schema level, where every object within a schema has shared level of access, which would vastly simplify permissions management (and could indeed be achieved with liquibase/flyway likes).
However I don't think this is a feasible change given our current state, but might be worth a think.

Yes i would say standard practice is to have your db model stord and deployed via db migrations. Even in a data warehouse you want to control and test changes, be able to roll back etc. Now if you are off loading that to the various data producers or ingestion pipelines, you would hope that they would offer similar features for change control, including user/role permissions. If not the recommended solution will prob vary with product.

yes ive seen examples of liquibase where they wtite scripts to grant acces to all the things in a schema to a role. I think this is what people are getting at the rbac, obvs if you are strict and keep the number of roles down the problem is much more managable

Just a Summary of discussion answer
The problem is quite specific to redshift in that tables need to be copied/recreated inorder to manage indexing and volume. This recreation is often managed by third party ingestion tools.
"normally" you would put your database schema into source control and deploy via

Change table in source control
Change permissions by role in source control
Build and test database/migration script
Run migration
new table with role based permissions is deployed
User permissions set to roles by dba/security are unaffected

However postgres source control tools are a bit limited in this regard and you may be forced to write manual scripts to apply the roles to tables after each deployment.
This can be simplified, by having a small set of basic roles. ie Read, Write, Admin and a script which loops through all the tables in a schema adding the permissions by role.
Obviously if you have a long complicated role set, this can also be done in the same way. But the mapping script will be ugly with hardcoded table and role relationships.
In your example with dbt, dbt does reapply the roles, so if you stick to a single tool you should be good. If you have a random combination of tools AND want to keep the permissions central it seems to me that you will have to be willing to give up on some of the tools features.
